# Input validation (Pep8 assembler)

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to write an input validation for my other program. If the input is smaller than -32,768 or larger than 32,767, the program has to print an error message and ask to repeat input, until it gets a number that is in the range (I have to use a loop). I know the code below has some logical errors. I tried to fix it, but it just leads to other logical errors. It's weird, because the numbers out of the range overlap with the numbers in the range. For example, -32,770, when added to Accumulator, is 32,766 (which IS in the range). This is what I have so far:

```
BR       isless 
input:    .BLOCK 2 
hello_ms: .ASCII "Enter a number: \x00"
error_ms: .ASCII "Wrong input, must be in the range -32,768 through 32,767. Enter a number: \x00"
thanx:    .ASCII "Thank you!\x00"
;
isless:  STRO    hello_ms, d
         DECI    input, d
         LDA     input, d
         CPA     32767, d ;-32769 
         BRLE    whileL
         BR      isgrter
whileL:  STRO    error_ms, d 
         DECI    input, d
         LDA     input, d
         CPA     32767, i
         BRLE    whileL
         BR      isgrter
isgrter: LDA     input, d
         CPA     -32768, i 
         BRGE    whileG
         BR      endwh
whileG:  STRO    error_ms, d 
         DECI    input, d
         LDA     input, d
         CPA     -32768, i 
         BRGE    whileG
         BR      endwh
endwh:   STRO    thanx, d 
         STOP
         .END
```

Comment: Since you have written that much, there is no reason you could not finish it on your own.  All the needed pieces and logic are present.  it is now simply a matter of checking whether the code matches the specification.

Comment: Well, I'm still confused because of this: " -32,770, when added to Accumulator, is 32,766 (which IS in the range)." I'm running on a lack of sleep and this assignment is due in an hour. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: With 16 bits in an integer, and one bit used to represent whether the number is negative, the range of numbers that can be represented is -32768 .. +32767. So when you add one to 32767 you get a negative number, and when you subtract one from -32768 you get a positive number.

Comment: I get that, but I still can't write a working code.

Comment: -32770 is less than -32768. If the result is 32766, I'm betting the accumulator started out with -3...

Comment: How big is the register in question? If the register is only 16 bits wide, then you can't actually represent any number outside the range!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you get decimal/numerical input larger than 16 bits? Can you for example input a 32-bit number? If so, you can easily check if the higher 16-bits are cleared or not.

**Edit**:

The DECI instruction sets the NZV flags.

Comment: In that case, the deci instruction must provide some flags to tell you whether the input number fits in 16 bits, like the carry flag. Or else every and any number will fit inside the range.

Comment: Looking at the instruction set, I can see that it modifies the NZV flags. Have a look at them.

Comment: Well, it's due in 13 mins.. I guess I'm going to lose points =(

Comment: Following where Jens is leading you there is no reason to be on 16 or 32 bit boundaries you can do 15 bit math or 12 bit or 8 bit or whatever splitting the value across two locations/registers.  That makes the overflow easier to detect without a need for processor specific flags.  If it is a flag thing you were supposed to find it is probably the v flag if there is one (signed overflow) the carry bit is unsigned overflow your problem has to do with signed overflow.

Comment: actually the V flag is usually a signed overflow, I dont know anything about this processor to know if that is consistent, and you have to examine what each instruction does to flags anyway.

Comment: Couldn't find a proper instruction set description, but the V flag is most probably what he wants to check.

Comment: SOLVED
Yes, the V flag was the way to go. Thanks everybody!